# How to update a value of a existing key in WeakMap?

Tags: javascript, weakmap

I can't find any example on MDN. I came up with this,

```js
const simpleMap = new WeakMap()

const simpleObject = {};

simpleMap.set(simpleObject, "A Value");

if(simpleMap.has(simpleObject)) {
  simpleMap.set(simpleObject, "A New Value");
 }
```

Is this way correct or shall I delete the key first before doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update directly.

```js
const simpleMap = new WeakMap()

const simpleObject = {};

simpleMap.set(simpleObject, "A Value");

if (simpleMap.has(simpleObject)) {
    simpleMap.set(simpleObject, "A New Value");
}

console.log(simpleMap.get(simpleObject));
```